# How to filter and replace HTML in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

I am using wordpress, and some pages are using page-template, which is almost full HTML without . Now I want to add GA code before , not sure it is a best way that I can filter the HTML output of page-template or maybe of theme, then I can replace  with GA code + . Any suggstion? Thanks a lot.

Cheer,
Mcwolf

Comment: What do you mean by "HTML without ."?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a plugin to inject google analytics to all your pages like
https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks, i will try it first.